# MySQL unexpectedly crashes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, out-of-memory, innodb

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I've got a few WordPress installations on my server.
Without warning, MySQL crashes every day on my server and I've yet to find the reason.

You can find the error.log below.

```
160721  9:25:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160721  9:25:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160721  9:25:44 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 40817296
160721  9:25:44  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 41068976
160721  9:25:45  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
160721  9:25:45  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160721  9:25:46 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 41068976
160721  9:25:46 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160721  9:25:46 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160721  9:25:46 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160721  9:25:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160721  9:25:46 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
160721 17:50:13 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160721 17:50:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160721 17:50:13  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160721 17:50:14  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 41400934
160721 17:50:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160721 17:50:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160721 17:50:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160721 17:50:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160721 17:50:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160721 17:50:16 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 41400934
160721 17:50:16 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160721 17:50:16 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160721 17:50:16 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160721 17:50:16 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160721 17:50:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
160722  5:44:00 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160722  5:44:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160722  5:44:00 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160722  5:44:00 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160722  5:44:00 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160722  5:44:00 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160722  5:44:00 [ERROR] Aborting

160722  5:44:00 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160722  5:44:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160722  5:44:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160722  5:44:01 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160722  5:44:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160722  5:44:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160722  5:44:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160722  5:44:01 [ERROR] Aborting

160722  5:44:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160722  5:50:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160722  5:50:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160722  5:50:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160722  5:50:31 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 41616363
160722  5:50:31  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 46858752
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 48741839
160722  5:50:31  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
160722  5:50:32  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160722  5:50:33 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 48741839
160722  5:50:33 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160722  5:50:33 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160722  5:50:33 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160722  5:50:33 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160722  5:50:33 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12

Case 1:  You have a tiny 1G server (or VM).  If so, lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to, say, 32M.

Case 2:  You have increased various other mysql settings to unreasonably high values.  Undo.

Case 3:  You have lots of applications in your small server; they are consuming most of RAM.  Find and fix.

If you need further assistance, tell us how much RAM you have, what else is running and provide `my.cnf`.

*Or* you could get more RAM.

Comment: Which case(s) do you have?